# Simulated annealing for least squares/ linear regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, optimization, least-squares

I am trying to optimize the solution of the linear regression problem by performing simulated annealing on the following loss function of least squares (MSE):

$$1/N (\sum (y_i-(ax_i+b))^2$$

I have studied a lot of examples of simulated annealing performed on functions with constant weights, but have not come across to something similar to that problem, which has a and b instead of constant numbers. Any ideas on how i could implement sa on that kind of equations? Should I somehow choose some constants to represent the a and b?

Comment: Do you want to implement SAnn or just solve LR with SAnn? For example: `myloss <- function(beta){sum((y-beta[1]-beta[2]*x )^2)}; N = 99; set.seed(N); x = runif(N); eps = rnorm(N); y = 1 + 3*x+ eps; optim(myloss, method= "SANN", par = c(2,2))` encodes a simple univariate LR task solve through SAnn. We can easily check this returns the same result as `lm(y ~x)`, is that what you want?

Comment: I would like to find a global minimum of the function, by implementing Sann from scratch, to better familiarize myself with that method. In the code you wrote, beta is given as an argument, so I will just input random numbers as beta values? Or should I acquire the best solution somehow?

Comment: Isn't this a convex problem? Why use simulated-annealing, which is designed for functions with many local minimum?

Comment: I guess, but my goal was to implement and compare several different optimization algorithms, just to get to know them better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulated annealing's fundamental mechanism is to compare the current state with a proposed state, then (probabilistically) decide whether to move to the proposed state or not.  In your case, "state" = "parameter estimates", because those are what you are trying to find the optimum values for.

We can set up a state vector $\theta_i = (a^*_i,b^*_i)$, the estimates of the parameters at iteration $i$.  You'll need to construct a proposal distribution which suggests a candidate $\theta_{i+1}$.  One such proposal distribution could be a Student-t centered at the current values of the parameters with a fairly low shape parameter $\nu$, e.g., $\nu = 3$.   (Having fat-tailed proposal distributions helps the algorithm get out of local minima.)  The scale of the proposal distribution would have to be problem-specific.

The following code is a very simple implementation of SA for solving the univariate regression $y_i = a + bx_i + e_i$, and may help to get you started:

```
simulated_annealing <- function(theta, y, x, scale = 0.1, max_iter = 1000, step = 0.05) {
   degrees_of_freedom <- length(y) - 2
   temp <- 1

   # Need to keep track of best state so far and current state
   # We also keep track of the iteration count of the best state for tuning purposes
   iter_best <- 1
   theta_best <- theta
   mse_best <- mse <- sum((y - theta[1] - theta[2]*x)^2) / degrees_of_freedom
   for (k in 1:max_iter) {     
      temp <- temp * (1 - step)

      # Generate proposals using a Student-t distribution      
      theta_prop <- theta + scale * rt(2, 3)
      mse_prop <- sum((y - theta_prop[1] - theta_prop[2]*x)^2) / degrees_of_freedom

      # Select the next state (either current or proposed)
      if (mse_prop < mse || runif(1) < exp(-(mse_prop-mse)/temp)) {
         theta <- theta_prop
         mse <- mse_prop

         if (mse_prop < mse_best) {
            iter_best <- k
            theta_best <- theta_prop
            mse_best <- mse_prop
         }
      }
   }
   return(list(iter_best=iter_best, mse_best=mse_best, theta_best=theta_best))
}
```

Now to try it out, removing lots of extraneous text from the output:

```
> x <- rnorm(100)
> y <- 1 + 2*x + rnorm(100)
> # Compare to linear regression estimates
> summary(lm(y~x))

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.06306    0.10117   10.51   <2e-16 ***
x            2.07854    0.09896   21.00   <2e-16 ***

Residual standard error: 1.009 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8182,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8164 

> # Starting values for SA parameter estimation: (0,0)
> simulated_annealing(c(0,0), y, x)
$iter_best
[1] 530

$mse_best
[1] 1.018276

$theta_best
[1] 1.061634 2.083421
```

We observe that our parameter estimates are very, very close to those of the linear regression.  Our RMSE is 1.009097, slightly higher than `lm`'s 1.009082 that we can calculate by saving the `lm` results as an object and examining the contents.